# UBUNTU 22 + NVIDIA second monitor brightness issue

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, brightness

I have a second monitor connected to the laptop and EVERY TIME I start the computer I am forced to set the screen brightness as the setting is always set back to the default Brightness 0, Constrat 0, Gamma 1

When I installed Ubuntu 22 I had this problem, but before the last update, when I opened NVIDIA Settings it automatically loaded the settings saved in .nvidia-settings-rc, but after a system update I am forced to configure manually every time it goes back to setting 0,0,1

Does anyone have any good references on how I can solve this problem?

Laptop config:
Ubuntu 22.04 | RTX 3070 | Driver Version: 535.86.05 | CUDA Version: 12.2